# $L_{1}$ Regression as LP

Tags: linear-programming, linear-regression

In solving the problem:

$$\underset{x}{\text{minimize}} \quad ||Ax - b||_{1}$$

We can formulate it as an LP by noting that:

$$||Ax-b||_{1} = \sum_{i} |a_{i}^{T}x - b_{i}|$$

In Boyd's book, they rewrite it as:

$$\underset{x}{\text{minimize}} \quad 1^{T} \mathbf{\delta}$$
   $$\text{subject to} \quad -1^{T} \mathbf{\delta} \leq Ax-b \leq 1^{T}\mathbf{\delta}$$

But shouldn't $\mathbf{\delta} \geq 0$? In other words, shouldn't the LP be:

$$\underset{x}{\text{minimize}} \quad 1^{T} \mathbf{\delta}$$
   $$\text{subject to} \quad -1^{T} \mathbf{\delta} \leq Ax-b \leq 1^{T}\mathbf{\delta}\quad
    \mathbf{\delta} \geq 0$$

Or is that distinction somehow implicit? Or does it even matter?

Comment: Is $\delta$ not a vector of terms of absolute values, and therefore positive in each component?  Or is $\delta$ defined differently?

Comment: Well, the idea is that, for each $i$, $\delta_{i} = | \mathbf{a}_{i}^{T} \mathbf{x} - b_{i}|$ where $\mathbf{a}_{i}$ is the $i$th row of a. But in Boyd's formulation, couldn't $\delta_{i}$ become negative during the LP solution, since we haven't explicitly constrained its sign in the LP reformulation?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that Boyd's book states:
$$ -1^T\delta \le Ax-b \le 1^T\delta$$

I think that should be: 
$$ -\delta \le Ax-b \le \delta$$

From this "sandwich equation" we can see that we require $-\delta \le \delta$ which implies $\delta \ge 0$.

So, $\delta \ge 0$ holds automatically.